# Laravel Dispatch Intercept/Customize

Tags: php, laravel

I basically want to do this: [Add custom field to Laravel queued job records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907972/add-custom-field-to-laravel-queued-job-records)

However the top-voted answer there doesn't really address how to do this, rather it advocates for a work-around.

I know in order to actually accomplish this I need to tap into the `dispatch` function. The issue is it isn't being called directly in my (in this case) event listener.

According to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dispatching-jobs) and [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-dispatch) `dispatch` is a global helper function. Where in the source code is this registered and how should I overwrite it in my event listener in order to run `handle()` (that which dispatch itself calls) in my `Job` class after a specified delay and yet be able to add additional entries/fields to the database?

My prime reason for this is because:

1). The job is sending a notificaiton via email.

2). Emails should only go out after a delay IF the user hasn't logged in/been active during that delay.

3). AND emails should only go out if that user doesn't have another email queued up since the first was dispatched, in which case the first should be consolidated and deleted into the second email.

Therefore I need additional database fields in order to find, delete and modify entries in the jobs table.

These ideas come from [an article on Medium](https://medium.com/@intercom/designing-smart-notifications-36336b9c58fb) which teaches that you don't want to spam users with emails/notifications and you need to consolidate/group/prioritize them and I'm trying to do this in Laravel.

I believe it is possible in Laravel but I am unsure how to overwrite the functionality when `dispatch` is a global and I don't know from where it is invoked. The Laravel docs on [the Command Bus](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus) don't go beyond Laravel 5.0.

**Edit:** I have to use Redis now, according to this (because I am getting that `beginTransaction()` error in my queue):

[Redis Driver > Database Driver](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19242#issuecomment-302107155)

I think a model watcher would be best but I'm not sure if `Job` is an Eloquent model. I need something that will work consistently across database drivers.

Comment: The command bus is the job queue in latest versions. Look at the `DispatchesJobs ` trait to see the source involved.

Answer (score -1):

When you create a job instance everything assigned to a public property is serialized and thereafter available to you during the job processing. You can pass in parameters to the job constructor and then assign them to properties like

```
public $foo;

public function __constructor($bar) {

    $this->foo = $bar;

}
```

Then in the handle function you can get the value $bar from `$this->foo`

Edit: If found this method within the `DatabaseQueue` class. Perhaps you could override to suit your needs:

```
/**
 * Create an array to insert for the given job.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $queue
 * @param  string  $payload
 * @param  int  $availableAt
 * @param  int  $attempts
 * @return array
 */
protected function buildDatabaseRecord($queue, $payload, $availableAt, $attempts = 0)
{
    return [
        'queue' => $queue,
        'attempts' => $attempts,
        'reserved_at' => null,
        'available_at' => $availableAt,
        'created_at' => $this->currentTime(),
        'payload' => $payload,
    ];
}
```

Comment: That's not my question however... I need to add/populate additional fields to the `jobs` database so that I'm not parsing through a serialized version of my data when searching the database. The trait you mention on your comment only links back to an interface as fair as I can tell.

Comment: What is your queue driver? Database? Redis? Are you dispatching from a controller? The are different ways dispatch is implemented as indicated by the interface.

Comment: `'database'` is the driver. I believe this file may be relevant: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Bus/BusServiceProvider.php

Comment: I'm dispatching from an event listener.

Comment: Why do you need to modify the dispatcher and not just pass in a constructor parameter? Like I said it gets serialized therefore it's stored with the job. You can create a new migration to add a column to the jobs table and update the row accordingly.

Comment: The job is entered into the database when? Before `handle()` correct? Because it is there before the delay expires. Therefore what you are suggesting seems to be to enter into the database twice, once on `dispatch`, another on `handle()`... is this the only option?

Comment: Something I thought of, maybe subscribe to Job model events, specifically creating, and add the new attribute then.

Comment: Could you post code to show how to do that, as I don't really follow.

Comment: It would be immediately after you call dispatch in the listener. Do you need it set when the record is created? Can you update the record later? At what point must it be absolutely?

Comment: Here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events. You can hook into the model lifecycle at any point.

Comment: I'd use the model events then for this. It'll be a much cleaner implementation saving you the trouble of overriding the dispatcher class.

Comment: Is a job considered an Eloquent model?I tried to do as you suggest and the provider never fired. Please post code. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events

Comment: Check my edit on my answer, I may have found an easier solution.